# How to choose bldc motors to use as generators?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, generator

First of all, sorry if I mess up certain words or terms, I am not very specialized in this department. I want to draw power out of an engine, producing around 50hp, or about 37kw of power. A normal generator head is too heavy to make sense in my application, and instead I want to use a large BLDC motor with a high thrust output (most likely a large drone motor) and rewire it to use as a generator. According to various sources, most motors have high amounts of efficiency, as generators if wired properly, and as such, I want to know how to choose bldc motors to use in this application? With my limited knowledge, I am currently thinking of going with a motor with an output of the power I want to convert, with a little headroom for efficiency loss, so around a 40kw motor. Basically, is this form of thinking correct, or would I have to choose a more powerful or less powerful motor, for decent efficiency converting this power?

Comment: A motor for 40kW to be used as a generator will likely be heavier than a generator specifically designed for 40kW.

Comment: If a motor is rated to spin at 1000RPM/V, then you can expect that if you spin it at 1000RPM it will produce about a 1V (ignoring loading). Basically, you probably want to be driving the motor as fast as it would be spinning if it were operating optimally as a motor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A motor with a 40 kW rating should be a reasonable match for your engine if the motor RPM matches the engine RPM. The engine will have an RPM at which it can produce the most power and potentially a different operating point at which its fuel efficiency is maximum. Assuming that you already have or have selected the engine, you should decide your desired engine operating point - speed and torque. Then select a motor can safely operate at that point. A motor will operate safely as a generator over some range of speed below its rated speed and possibly a little above. The motor power rating will vary with speed. You need to look for a motor with detailed speed vs. torque specifications. You will also need to determine what output voltage you want and what motor (generator) speed will produce that voltage.

Comment: I suspect that a motor sold as a permanent-magnet synchronous motor may be a better choice than one sold as a bldc motor.